# vector.resize isn't increasing size of the vector in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I am a c++ beginner.  I was practicing how to work with class and header files. The program manages *Rents of a building*. It has a `Rent` class and a `Floor` class. Here're some definitions of those classes.

**rent.cpp** (Copied important functions only)

---

Manages information about `Floor`s and has `vector<Floor> paid_by_floors;` property.

```
#include "rent.hh"

void Rent::set_floor_count(int count){
    this->paid_per_floors.reserve(count);
    this->paid_per_floors.resize(count);
}

void Rent::set_floor(int index, Floor floor){
    this->paid_per_floors[index] = floor;
}

Floor Rent::get_floor(int index){
    return this->paid_per_floors[index];
}
```

**floor.cpp** (Copied important functions only)

---

Manages information about rooms and has `vector<Floor> paid_by_rooms;` property.

```
#include "floor.hh"

void Floor::set_room_count(int count){
    this->paid_per_rooms.resize(count, 0);
}

int Floor::get_room_amount(int index){
    return this->paid_per_rooms[index];
}

void Floor::set_room_amount(int index, int amount){
    this->paid_per_rooms.push_back(amount);
    // Tried with paid_per_rooms[index] = amount;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    Rent m_rent(5);
    cout << m_rent.get_floor_count() << endl; // stdout line:1

    m_rent.set_floor_count(2);
    cout << m_rent.get_floor_count() << endl; // stdout line:2 (correct)

    m_rent.get_floor(0).set_room_count(5);
    cout << m_rent.get_floor(0).get_room_count() << endl; // stdout lines:3 (incorrect)

    m_rent.get_floor(0).set_room_amount(0, 100);
    m_rent.get_floor(0).get_room_amount(0); // stdout line:4 (seg fault)

    return 0;
}
```

And output on `stdout`.

```
5
2
0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As you can see When I change the size of the `paid_per_floors` vector. It works. But, it does not work with `paid_per_rooms`. Also, it returns a segmentation fault which stands for `OutOfBound`. How should I fix it?

### Did Some Research Before

Searched on google about this problem with queries like ***vector resize does not work***, ***vector resize does not increase size***. The answers were to use `push_back` without array indexing like `vec[0]`. In `set_room_count` function I have also used `reserve` before `resize`. But, the problem didn't get fixed.

Comment: This question would benefit greatly from a [mre], rather than lots of code with missing parts.

Comment: `Floor Rent::get_floor(int index);` As a beginner you should start with reading a [book on C++ basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). That book will explain what the difference between returning a value (`Floor`) and a reference (`Floor&`) is.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First thing to find out where your understanding differs from how it actually works is to come up with an example that does reproduce the problem. And *only* the problem. Such an example should not be about floors and rooms, but just about a vector and its size, self-cobtained and compilable. You will find that coming up with such an example will solve the problem most of the times, as the error becomes apparent.

Comment: `Copied important functions only`: If it is broken how do you know you have copied the important functions! I don't see `get_floor()` which seems rather important.

Comment: @MartinYork I'm sorry. I missed it while editing to decrease codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
Floor Rent::get_floor(int index) {
    return this->paid_per_floors[index];
}
```

returns a copy of the Floor object and you apply the reservation to the copy while the original object is still unchanged.

You should return a reference so that you will change the original object:

```
Floor& Rent::get_floor(int index) {
    return this->paid_per_floors[index];
}
```

Comment: It helped. Thank You. Now it returns 5 for room_count as expected.